# open jquery modal dialog on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a page, i want it to display some content in a modal dialog (jquery UI dialog) as soon as the page is loaded.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#example").dialog();
  });

<div id="example" class="flora" title="This is my title">
    I'm in a dialog!
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: So what's wrong with the code you provided? Is it not working or...? As far as I can see, that would work perfectly. I would suggest you use $(function() { instead of $(document).ready(function(){. It's shorter and easier to read. :P

Comment: I second their question below.  it looks okay, what problem are you experiencing

Answer (score 5):

Your div tag isn't properly formatted and it needs to be closed.  The following worked for me, but it needs proper CSS files.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="jquery/jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#example").dialog({modal: true});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example" class="flora" title="This is my title">
        I'm in a dialog!
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wayne Khan is right in that

> the default behavior is to open when you call dialog(), unless you set autoOpen to false.

and tvanfosson has it nearly correct, though the default dialog is not Modal.  To display a modal window, you must set the **`modal`** option to **`true`**

To illustrate, here's a trimmed-down excerpt from a [small project](http://drfloob.com/code/3:incomeagain) I was working on tonight:

```
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./init.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#exampleNode').dialog({
            modal: 'true'
        });
    });
</script>
...
```

---

For your reference:

- [The jQuery Dialog Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog) (see the bottom for a styling reference)
- [A Modal Dialog example](http://ui.jquery.com/demos/dialog/#modal)
- My small MIT licensed project, which has a modal dialog: [inComeAgain?](http://drfloob.com/uploads/inComeAgain/)